# finding smallest number in list for python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a for loop to get an average for each week and for the month in python:

```
sum = 0
sumA = 0
sumB = 0
sumC = 0
sumD = 0

week1 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
week2 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
week3 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
week4 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)

for x in (week1):
    sum = sum + week1[x]
    avg1 = (sum + week1[x]) / 7
for y in (week2):
    sumA = sumA + week2[y]
    avg2 = (sumA + week2[y]) / 7
for z in (week3):
    sumB = sumB + week3[z]
    avg3 = (sumB + week3[z]) / 7
for k in (week4):
    sumC = sumC + week4[k]
    avg4 = (sumC + week4[k]) / 7

sumD = sum + sumA + sumB + sumC
avg = (sum + sumA + sumB + sumC) / 28
```

that is it but its not correct. can i get some help please

Comment: What output do you get, what do you expect?

Comment: not a good idea to use 'sum', as it's a builtin function. and if a 'for' loop isn't required, you could make a much simpler, more maintainable script using 'sum'.

Comment: for loops in Python can be considered a code smell, especially when it's for calculating a numeric quantity.  Python lends itself more to a functional approach.  See e.g. map/reduce http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

Comment: @I28Much: No, they're not "code smells", they're an important part of the language and used well in a billion functions. Not using builtin functions when appropriate, on the other hand, is indeed no good.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Python 2.x, the `/` operator for two integers uses integer divsion, i. e. the result of the division is rounded down to the next integer.  Try it in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> 5/3
1
```

To get the correct floating point division, either use

```
from __future__ import division
```

or convert one of the operands to `float` first

```
avg = float(sum + sumA + sumB + sumC) / 28
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need these loops. Here's a quick example:

```
>>> week1 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
>>> average1 = sum(week1) / len(week1)
>>> average1
34
```

As in the comments:

The above example (in Python 2.x) needs one part cast to float if you want 'true' division (e.g. 34.71).

In Python 3.x the single `/` division defaults to 'true' division so the above *snippet* would be correct (although with a different resulting value for `average1`).

Comment: Except that the average is really 34.71.

Comment: I have to use a pair of nested for loops

Comment: @ChristopheD  - No, `//` is integer division - you should have done something like `float(sum(week1))/len(week1)`

Comment: @user691693: Seriously? Then you might want to consider adding a homework tag.

Comment: @user691693 - why? if this is homework, please tag it as such

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems here. First, `for x in lst` yields the elements of `lst`, not the indices. Second, you add in the elements twice, once when updating `sum`, then again when updating `avg`. Just compute `avg` outside the list. Third, divide by a `float` instead of an `int` to prevent truncation:

```
for x in (week1):
    sum = sum + x
avg1 = sum / 7.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [....]
avg = sum(list)/float(len(list))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def ave(numbers):
...  return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
... 
>>> week1 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
>>> week2 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
>>> week3 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
>>> week4 = (35,38,30,34,27,40,39)
>>> ave(week1)
34
>>> ave(week1+week2+week3+week4)
34
>>>
```

---

As others pointed out, use `from __future__ import division` if you want a non-truncated result